# Flutter layout without AppBar

Tags: flutter

I need a layout without an appbar, so the most obvious approach is to just leave out the `appbar` tag on the `Scaffold` but if I do that the content goes underneath the status bar like this:

[image]

As you can see my container which is colored in blue starts right from underneath the status bar which shouldn't be the case, so I had to manually set the margin of the container which is not so nice, this is the results:

[image]

I have this feeling that devices might have status bars with varying heights so setting my top margin to fixed size might not render properly on other devices. Is there a way for flutter to position my content automatically below the status like it positions the `AppBar` nicely below the status bar.

Here is my scaffold code:

```
return new Scaffold(
      body: new Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          new HeaderLayout(),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

This is my header container:

```
class HeaderLayout extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0),
      child: new SizedBox(
        height: 80.0,
        child: new Center(
          child: new Text(
              "Recommended Courses",
              style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Use can use the widget SafeArea. It has the same effect as: margin: MediaQuery.of(context).padding

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can get the OS padding with `MediaQuery`.

You'd have to replace your

```
margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0),
```

by

```
margin: MediaQuery.of(context).padding,
```

Another solution is to wrap your content inside a `SafeArea`. Which basically does the same thing.

Comment: Thank you for that, I had to use padding instead and it worked. Thank you so much

Answer (score 68):

Wrap your Column with SafeArea

```
  body: new SafeArea(
      child: new Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          new HeaderLayout(),
        ],
      )
  ) ,
```

[SafeArea](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html) is a widget that insets its child by sufficient padding to avoid intrusions by the operating system.
For example, this will indent the child by enough to avoid the status bar at the top of the screen.

[image]

Comment: If we have scrollable content without an app bar, then SafeArea does not solve the scroll behind the status bar. Do you know how can we solve scrolling behind the status bar?

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.blue, // navigation bar color
    statusBarColor: Colors.pink, // status bar color
  ));
}
```

Comment: Add comment on the mechanics of this snippet. Plain code snippet encourages the copy-paste culture.