# Flutter application design without AppBar

Tags: dart, flutter

I tried using this kind of approach to have all of my UI (here only a `Text`) in the application **below** the **status bar**, but *without **AppBar***:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      title: "example",
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Text("text widget"),
      ),
    ));
```

This question was already *asked* once similar to my text, but [the answer to it (which is also *accepted*)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49554573/6509751) only takes `margin` into account. This, to me, does not seem like a satisfying solution, especially because you need to access `MediaQuery.of(context).padding`, where I could not even figure out how to use `context` in my simple example.

My code gives me the following result:

[image: get]

But I want to see this:

[image: want]

Now to make the differenciation between my question and the other question clear: I am not searching for a **margin**, I am searching for a legitimate idiomatic way of doing this. What I mean with this might look like this:

```
ScaffoldWithoutAppBar(body: ...
```

Obviously this does not exist, but I do not want *a margin fix*.

Comment: What do you mean by _don't wan't a margin fix_ ? This clearly looks like a margin fix to me

Comment: @RémiRousselet I mean that I want the normal application behavior that I would get in native Android or iOS layout design, which can be achieved with `SafeArea`.

Comment: Well yeah. But in the end it's strictly the same thing. `SafeArea` do the `MediaQuery.of(context).padding` you didn't want to.

Comment: @RémiRousselet Yes, of course. But I was searching for an idiomatic way. If you look closely at the end of my question you can see that I wrote `ScaffoldWithoutAppBar(body: ...` and `SafeArea(child: ...` is what I meant with this. Obviously it is not a `Scaffold`, but I just used the word to deliver my point. I think that it is very unidiomatic to handle tasks like this in your own code.

Comment: Note: Now the `new` keyword isn't required at all

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Wrap your page content (Text or Scaffold) inside a [SafeArea](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html) widget

> A widget that insets its child by sufficient padding to avoid intrusions by the operating system.

```
return new SafeArea(child: new Text('text widget'));
```

Comment: Obviously I cannot wrap a `Text` widget inside in the `SafeArea` on its own. I need to wrap that into a `Material`.

Comment: Using this answer I'm getting the screen with black background and without any styles applied to the text element.

Comment: It is implied that you have a parent Scaffold and above that ideally a MaterialApp

Answer (score 2):

first solution: My favorite solution

```
 appBar: PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top),
    child: SizedBox(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top,
    ),
  ),
```

solution (2):

```
body: SafeArea(
        top: true,
        left: false,
        right: false,
        bottom: false,
        child:Container(),
)
```

solution (3):

```
body: ListView(
children:[],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the `Scaffold` into `SafeArea`, as below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp(
  textInput: Text("Text Widget"),
));

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget textInput;
  MyApp({this.textInput});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool checkBoxValue = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctxt) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: SafeArea(
           child: Scaffold(
              body: new Center(
              child: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                widget.textInput,
                Checkbox(
                    value: checkBoxValue,
                    onChanged: (bool newValue){
                      setState(() {
                        checkBoxValue = newValue;
                      });
                    }
                )
              ],
            ))),
          ),
      );
  }
}
```

About the opposite, in case you do not need to keep repeating the `AppBar` in your multiple screens, you can create separate widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'state.dart';

AppBar commonAppBar(String title, void action()) {
  return new AppBar(
    title: new Text(title),
    actions: [
      new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.flip), onPressed: action),
      new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.exit_to_app), onPressed: () {
        new StateSubject().switchToLogin();
      }),
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: `Column` needs a `top-level` to be wrapped to, so can not b wrapped directly to the `SafeArea`.