# Material App styles doesn't work without Scaffold

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I'm trying to create a Material design app without the Scaffold element: Here is the purely default app:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(widget.title);
  }
}
```

The result is:

[image: screenshot]

How to fix that and use material styles without Scaffold?

**Answer:**

I need to use the `Material` widget. As a very beginner in Flutter I had read Material design tutorials and all of them were using the `Scaffold` widget. Thanks for pointing out the `Material` widget in comments.

Comment: Why not use scaffold? scaffold is a material widget and makes our lives a lot easier. A LOT easier. If you really really don't want to use scaffold, then use the Material widget.

Comment: if you want your `primarySwatch: Colors.blue,` to take effect you have to use `Scaffold` - see `material/scaffold.dart` source file, line ~2111 (in version 1.10.15) where theme is read and then in line 2323 is set `Material.color` - what is wrong with using "bare" `Scaffold`?

Comment: I'm confused by the fact that I pass theme data to the application but it has no effect on the widgets placed in it. By the way, thanks for pointing to the Material widget!

Comment: your welcome. here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scaffold.dart#L2341 you have where `Scaffold` uses `Matarial` widget

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It will not work without scaffold.

I think you are not getting what scaffold is and how it's behaviour is?

**Scaffold** is a widget which provides your screen/route a default behaviour similar to your android/ios screens like AppBar, Body, Title, FloatingActionButton, Drawer etc.

So that you do not have to make yourself a new structure.

If you are not using scaffold, then your page will act like a plain body structure in which you have to fill custom widgets as per your requirements.

For ex :

In android, Any Activity will have a default ActionBar. But, if you use NoActionBarActivity then Activity will be displayed without actionBar.

Even **Scaffold** works in the similar manner.

**Updated Method :**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(child: Center(child: Text(widget.title,)),color: Colors.white,);
  }
```

You need to use **Material Widget** as a parent to behave the child widgets in the similar manner when using Scaffold.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I don't want to use Scaffold because I don't need the floating action button and action bar. I can use a SafeArea, for example. But I still need controls styles according to the Material design. I'm confused by the fact that I pass theme data to the App object but it doesn't affet widgets placed in this app, even a simple text box.

Comment: Can you add your code here so that i can understand what exactly you want to achieve ? Also, I want to tell you is that if you don't want to use properties like floatingactionButton, drawer, appBar then it is fine. they are optional. Just carry on with the widgets you want to use like body, appbar. Otherwise creating a custom scaffold for yourself will waste your time as per my thinking. Still if you want to use a custom Scaffold then refer the Scaffold Widget first to move ahead.

Comment: The code is in the question. I need to get a white background and standard black text with the Roboto font. When using Scaffold without app bar, it leads to the following issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50091640/flutter-application-design-without-appbar. I will add some controls later by myself, without using app bar, action bar or floating action buttons.

Comment: Checkout the updated method. Again, i want to remind you that yellow underline with the black background and text is not an issue. It is just a default behaviour without using widgets with Material behaviour in flutter. As your widgets in your build method are not inside the Material widget in any manner either it is scaffold or anything else then it will be not behave as it will inside material widget.

I think this will sort your issue.

Comment: I didn't know about the `Material` widget. I've very beginner and all the tutorials I read were using Scaffold. Now I know, thanks!

Comment: could you add a mention about the Material widget to your answer, please? I think it will be the full answer and will mark it.