# How to set BackdropFilter to Appbar and BottomNavigationBar?

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanna set `BackdropFilter` to the whole screen but it sets only for body, not the `AppBar` and `BottomNavigationBar` ones. Here is the sample of my code:

```
Scaffold(
appbar: AppBar(
  title: 'Hello'
),
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
  ///...
),  
body: Stack(
  children: [
    Conatiner( /* ... */ ),
    if (/*condition to blur */) ...[
      BackdropFilter(
        filter: ImageFilter.blur(
          sigmaX: 5,
          sigmaY: 5
        ),
        child: Container()
      ),
      Container(
        child: /* something appears above blur */
      ),  
    ]
    ]
  )
)
```

Is it possible to blur all element on the screen?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use OverlayEntry:

```
class BlurBackground {
  static void show({@required BuildContext context, @required OverlayEntry overlayEntry}) {
    overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(builder: (context) {
      return Positioned(
          top: 0,
          child: BackdropFilter(
    filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5, sigmaY: 5),
    child: Container(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0)),
  ),),
    });

    Overlay.of(context).insert(overlayEntry);
  }
}
```

OR

Wrap Scaffold & BackdropFilter in Stack:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('TabBar Demo'),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: GestureDetector(
              child: Text('test'),
              onTap: () {
                showTimePicker(
                  context: context,
                  helpText: "",
                  initialTime: TimeOfDay(hour: 10, minute: 47),
                  initialEntryMode: TimePickerEntryMode.input,
                  builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
                    return MediaQuery(
                      data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(
                        alwaysUse24HourFormat: true,
                      ),
                      child: child,
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
        BackdropFilter(
          filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5, sigmaY: 5),
          child: Container(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0)),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: Second solution works great for me, but in container (I edit code in question) that should be above blured background, theme is resetting. Why this is happens? Is this because container  placed not in Scaffold? Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Oh, I see, I didn't use Material widget as a parent, this helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58678614/material-app-styles-doesnt-work-without-scaffold